# Conditionally setting html parameters in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, parameters, radio-button, conditional-statements

I have a pair of radio buttons that I want to pre-assign a `checked` value to only my `new` action. Right now I'm conditionally rendering two partials. One partial that has radio buttons with `checked` attributes and the other with not attributes at all:

```
<%= form_for([@restaurant, @dish_review], url: :restaurant_dish_reviews) do |f| %>
  <% if action_name == "new" %>
    <%= render "status_buttons_checked", f: f, dish: @dish %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render "status_buttons", f: f %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

_**status_buttons_checked**

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.radio_button :status, :upvoted, checked: current_user.voted_up_on?(dish) %>
    <%= f.label :status, value: :upvoted %>

    <%= f.radio_button :status, :downvoted, checked: current_user.voted_down_on?(dish) %>
    <%= f.label :status, value: :downvoted %>
</div>
```

---

_**statsus_buttons**

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.radio_button :status, :upvoted, checked: current_user.voted_up_on?(dish) %>
    <%= f.label :status, value: :upvoted %>

    <%= f.radio_button :status, :downvoted, checked: current_user.voted_down_on?(dish) %>
    <%= f.label :status, value: :downvoted %>
</div>
```

I was wondering if there was any way in Rails where I can insert the conditional in the `radio_button` parameter instead of creating two partials. I'd like to something similar to what's show below but run into a template error:

```
<%= f.radio_button :status, :downvoted, if action_name == "new" current_user.voted_down_on?(dish) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `form_for`, the form methods you use are automatically populated with the appropriate data for your attributes. Whilst I don't know if this works with the `checked` value, it means that if you have the following:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

... `:name` will be populated from your `@user` object (if it's `new`, no data will be inserted).

--

This means that if you're using `form_for`, you should be able to populate the `checked` value with the data passed to the view:

```
<%= form_for [@restaurant, @dish_review] do |f| %>
   <%= f.radio_button :status, :upvoted, checked: current_user.voted_up_on? @dish %>
   <%= f.radio_button :status, :downvoted, checked: current_user.voted_down_on? @dish %>
<% end %>
```

I don't see what you're trying to achieve from your partials (they're both the same) -- but if you wanted to create "checked" on conditions, you'd be able to use the following:

```
   <%= checked = action_name == "new"
   <%= f.radio_button :status, :downvoted, checked: checked %>
```

This will set the value as "true" or "false" depending on whether the action is `new` or not.